# Kivy-ios: problems after launching the iOS simulator in Xcode environment

Tags: ios, xcode, kivy, simulator, bundle-identifier

Details

After the packaging shown here https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios and the building phase of Kivy project, Xcode tries to launch it on iOS simulator but this
problem appears.

What could it depend on?

```
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-12-22 08:47:38 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "launchApplicationWithID:options:pid:error:";
}
--
Application launch for '...' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone14,7";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.4 (20E247)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 3350;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator16.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.3 (Build 22E252)
Xcode 14.3.1 (21815) (Build 14E300c)
Timestamp: 2023-12-22T09:47:38+01:00
```

I'm trying to work on the Bundle Identifier without success. I tried to clean build folder and restart simulator without success.

Answer (score 0):

Solved from terminal installing Rosetta 2

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```